# How to create jQuery array from c# variable from SQL SELECT query

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

when my page loads I run a SQL SELECT to get a c# variable

```
var row = db.QuerySingle(myquery, someID);    
var positionTags = row.PosTag;
```

the result is in the form:

```
"tag1,tag2,tag3,..."
```

I'm try to get this to a jquery Array with elements separated by the commas with the following

```
var positionTagsJS = ['@positionTags'];
```

however positionTagsJS shows up as an array with just 1 element.

```
tag1,tag2,tag3,...
```

I also tried to create an array from my initial c# variable as follows:

```
Array positionTagsArray = positionTags.Split(',');    
positionTags = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(positionTagsArray);
```

This leaves me with something in the form:

```
"[\"tag1\",\"tag2\",\"tag3\",\"...\"]"
```

and when I run it through my script

```
var positionTagsJS = ['@positionTags'];
```

I get...

`[&quot;tag1&quot;,&quot;tag2&quot;,&quot;tag3&quot;,&quot;...&quot;]`

So, what is the most efficient way to get a java script and/or jQuery array of the form

["tag1","tag2","tag3","..."]

It probably doesn't matter but ultimately this array will be used to activate a jQuery UI selecatables widget.

Comment: Are you familiar with [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)?

Comment: Hi Mike. I picked up the .Net 'Split' from another thread and used it above. I'm not familiar with the c# 'split' but assume it must be similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the second option, but assign the value like this:

```
var positionTagsJS = @Html.Raw(positionTags);
```

Comment: That works. I'm not sure why I don't need the square brackets [ ] to get my array but this method seems to give me an array with length equal to the number of comman separated items in the original c# string variable.

Comment: You don't need the brackets because the json string already has them.